# How to make bootstrap thumbnail image auto-size?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 img-thumbnail"><img src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/04LDEYRW59.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 img-thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/90V03Q5Y60.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 img-thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/O83SF2RB6D.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 rimg-thumbnail"><img src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/5JVPSVP7EI.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 img-thumbnail"><img src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/C5Y10KIIHA.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 img-thumbnail"><img src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/YSSFRY5B25.jpg" alt=""></div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

I am trying to show images in the Bootstrap Grid System I used the img-thumbnail class but it showing a very large image and when I make the screen size small the image is not changing it still show the large image. I want to reduce the size of my images as per the requirement of the screen? how to do this? I mean if I want to make a large 960px screen it should show the large image if I make a small screen it should show a small image I mean to resize by itself. I searched for this problem and  I found this solution in the stack-overflow but it was not helpful for me.

```
    .thumbnail{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Thank you all In advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add an ***img-fluid*** class on each *img* tag to make it responsive.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 img-thumbnail"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/04LDEYRW59.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 img-thumbnail"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/90V03Q5Y60.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 img-thumbnail"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/O83SF2RB6D.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 img-thumbnail"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/5JVPSVP7EI.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 img-thumbnail"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/C5Y10KIIHA.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 img-thumbnail"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/YSSFRY5B25.jpg" alt=""></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Image-thumbnail class use in img tag not in the div

Answer (score 0):

I am removing div **img-thumbnail** class & applied to img tag

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-6"><img src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/04LDEYRW59.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-6"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/90V03Q5Y60.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-6"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/O83SF2RB6D.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-6"><img src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/5JVPSVP7EI.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-6"><img src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/C5Y10KIIHA.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-6"><img src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/YSSFRY5B25.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" alt=""></div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set height and width in 'Percentage' ,Not in px.

```
e.g :    .thumbnail{
         width: 70%;
         height: 30%;
         overflow: auto;
         }
```

Comment: i don't think that is the problem i should write the img-thumbnail in image tag instead of div. i tried that also. However thank you bro for replaying